# Error al intentar convertir fecha en LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, date

Estoy utilizando **LINQ** e intento convertir una fecha a un formato especifico y obtengo el siguiente error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Parte de mi consulta en **LINQ** es la siguiente

```
select new TicketReportAux
                    {
                        TicketId = tblTickets.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID,
                        TicketFolio = tblTickets.FOLIO,
                        TicketAplicant = tblTickets.CUSTOMER_FULLNAME,
                        TicketSubjet = tblTickets.TITLE,
                        TicketStatus = tblStatus.NAME,
                        TicketService = tblServices.NAME,
                        TicketEmployee = tblEmployee.FULLNAME,
                        TicketCreateDate = tblRecords.ACTIVITY_DATE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    };

                foreach (TicketReportAux rowAux in basicReport)
                {
                    rowAux.TicketEmployee = rowAux.TicketEmployee.IsEmpty() ? "" : rowAux.TicketEmployee;
                    result.BasicReport.Add(rowAux);
                }

                result.Success = true;
                result.Message = "op_exitosa";
```

Adjunto para mayor claridad la imagen del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Convierto la fecha de la siguiente manera

```
TicketCreateDate = tblRecords.ACTIVITY_DATE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Pero me genera el error que les comento, pueden ayudarme a solucionarlo o a indicarme la forma correcta de hacerlo, se ha intentado con las siguientes declaraciones pero no se consigue resultado

```
TicketCreateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tblRecords.ACTIVITY_DATE).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
TicketCreateDate = DateTime.Parse(tblRecords.ACTIVITY_DATE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Tu error se da porque Linq to entities no soporta `ToString()`, no sabe como traducirlo, antes de usarlo, si o si tenes que forzar que se ejecute la query con un `ToList()` o `AsEnumerable()`, sino, otra opción, puede ser usar `SqlFunctions`, en esta [pregunta de soen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370402/entity-framework-4-linq-how-to-convert-from-datetime-to-string-in-a-query) tenes mucha información del tema

Comment: De pura o simple casualidad, ¿Has intentado pasar de frente esto: `TicketCreateDate = tblRecords.ACTIVITY_DATE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un clásico en Entity Framework, se soluciona de la siguiente manera:

Antes del bloque donde están las setencias del EF, crea una variable temporal:

```
var TicketCreateDateTEMP = tblRecords.ACTIVITY_DATE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Ahora con esa variable tempora, dentro del `select new`:

Reemplaza:

```
TicketCreateDate = tblRecords.ACTIVITY_DATE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Por:

```
TicketCreateDate = TicketCreateDateTEMP
```

Presta mucha atención a los tipos de variables que estás pasando, si ambas clases contienen strings como propiedad o si son datetime.

Si recién estás empezando y/o quieres mejorar y dominar Entity Framwork, te recomiendo este sitio: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

**Actualización**

Quizás funcione usar la cláusula `let`, según [la documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause):

**let (Cláusula, Referencia de C#)**

En una expresión de consulta, a veces resulta útil almacenar el resultado de una subexpresión para usarlo en las cláusulas siguientes. Puede hacer esto con la palabra clave let, que crea una variable de rango y la inicializa con el resultado de la expresión que proporcione. Una vez inicializada con un valor, la variable de rango no se puede usar para almacenar otro valor. En cambio, si la variable de rango contiene un tipo consultable, se puede consultar.

Por lo tanto, aquí el código:

```
  ).Max()
  //Esta linea:
  let TicketCreateDateTEMP = tblRecords.ACTIVITY_DATE.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

                select new TicketReportAux
                {
                    TicketId = tblTickets.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID,
                    TicketFolio = tblTickets.FOLIO,
                    TicketAplicant = tblTickets.CUSTOMER_FULLNAME,
                    TicketSubjet = tblTickets.TITLE,
                    TicketStatus = tblStatus.NAME,
                    TicketService = tblServices.NAME,
                    TicketEmployee = tblEmployee.FULLNAME,                        
                    TicketCreateDate = TicketCreateDateTEMP 
                };
```

Comment: Al realizar esto me indica que `tblRecords` no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: Antes de dar negativos. Evalúa los motivos. Edita tu pregunta y agrega todos el código que tienes que nos permita reproducir tu escenario.

Comment: Revisa nuevamente la pregunta, ya se actualizo justificando los motivos

Comment: Intente con otras formas sentencias pero aun no consigo el resultado

Comment: @SebastianSalazar Coloca un breakpoint donde creas conveniente para que puedas extraer la información que tienes en `tblRecords.ACTIVITY_DATE`, ese valor lo agregas a tu pregunta.

Comment: También agrega la definición de la clase `TicketReportAux`