# Diferencia en días entre dos fechas linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, linq

Tengo la siguiente consulta y para Dias necesita el calculo de dias entre dos fecha pero no lo consigo.
Aqui mi codigo:

```
    [HttpGet("{IdProdAuditoria}")]
    public ActionResult Get(int IdProdAuditoria)
    {
      try
      {
      var item = (from l in _context.ProdLogAccionesCorrectivas
        join a in _context.ProdLogAuditoria on l.IdLogAuditoria equals a.Id
        join c in _context.ProdAudInocCat on a.IdCatAuditoria equals c.Id
        join p in _context.ProdAudInoc on a.IdProdAuditoria equals p.Id
        join f in _context.ProdAuditoriaFoto on l.Id equals f.IdLogAC into F
        from f in F.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where a.IdProdAuditoria == IdProdAuditoria
        group l by new
        {
        IdLogAC = l.Id,
        IdLog = a.Id,
        IdCatAuditoria = a.IdCatAuditoria,
        NoPunto = c.NoPunto,
        Nivel=c.Nivel,
        NoPuntoDesc = c.NoPuntoDesc,
        PuntoControl = c.PuntoControl,
        PuntoControlDesc = c.PuntoControlDesc,
        Justificacion = l.Justificacion,
        Opcion = a.Opcion,
        isOpen = false,
        FotoAC = f.IdLogAC,
        Dias = ((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - p.Fecha_termino)).Days    
        } into x
        select new
        {
        IdLogAC = x.Key.IdLogAC,
        IdLog = x.Key.IdLog,
        IdCatAuditoria = x.Key.IdCatAuditoria,
        NoPunto = x.Key.NoPunto,
        Nivel = x.Key.Nivel,
        NoPuntoDesc = x.Key.NoPuntoDesc,
        PuntoControl = x.Key.PuntoControl,
        PuntoControlDesc = x.Key.PuntoControlDesc,
        Justificacion = x.Key.Justificacion,
        Opcion = x.Key.Opcion,
        isOpen = x.Key.isOpen,
        FotoAC = x.Key.FotoAC,
        Dias = x.Key.Dias,
        }).Distinct();

        return Ok(item.ToList());
        }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
       }
     }
```

El error es:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ProdLogAccionesCorrectivas>
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<ProdLogAuditoria>, 
        inner: p => p.IdLogAuditoria, 
        outerKeySelector: p0 => p0.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: (p, p0) => new TransparentIdentifier<ProdLogAccionesCorrectivas, ProdLogAuditoria>(
            Outer = p, 
            Inner = p0
        ))
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<ProdAudInocCat>, 
        inner: ti => ti.Inner.IdCatAuditoria, 
        outerKeySelector: p1 => (Nullable<int>)p1.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: (ti, p1) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<ProdLogAccionesCorrectivas, ProdLogAuditoria>, ProdAudInocCat>(
            Outer = ti, 
            Inner = p1
        ))
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<ProdAudInoc>, 
        inner: ti0 => ti0.Outer.Inner.IdProdAuditoria, 
        outerKeySelector: p2 => (Nullable<int>)p2.Id, 
        innerKeySelector: (ti0, p2) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<ProdLogAccionesCorrectivas, ProdLogAuditoria>, ProdAudInocCat>, ProdAudInoc>(
            Outer = ti0, 
            Inner = p2
        ))
    .LeftJoin(
        outer: DbSet<ProdAuditoriaFoto>, 
        inner: ti1 => (Nullable<int>)ti1.Outer.Outer.Outer.Id, 
        outerKeySelector: p3 => p3.IdLogAC, 
        innerKeySelector: (ti1, p3) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<ProdLogAccionesCorrectivas, ProdLogAuditoria>, ProdAudInocCat>, ProdAudInoc>, ProdAuditoriaFoto>(
            Outer = ti1, 
            Inner = p3
        ))
    .Where(ti2 => ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Inner.IdProdAuditoria == __IdProdAuditoria_0)
    .GroupBy(
        source: ti2 => new { 
            IdLogAC = ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Id, 
            IdLog = ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Inner.Id, 
            IdCatAuditoria = ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Inner.IdCatAuditoria, 
            NoPunto = ti2.Outer.Outer.Inner.NoPunto, 
            Nivel = ti2.Outer.Outer.Inner.Nivel, 
            NoPuntoDesc = ti2.Outer.Outer.Inner.NoPuntoDesc, 
            PuntoControl = ti2.Outer.Outer.Inner.PuntoControl, 
            PuntoControlDesc = ti2.Outer.Outer.Inner.PuntoControlDesc, 
            Justificacion = ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Justificacion, 
            Opcion = ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Inner.Opcion, 
            isOpen = False, 
            FotoAC = ti2.Inner.IdLogAC, 
            Dias = ((TimeSpan)((Nullable<DateTime>)DateTime.Now - ti2.Outer.Inner.Fecha_termino)).Days
         }, 
        keySelector: ti2 => ti2.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: A lo mejor lo que buscas es `TotalDays`en lugar de `Days`

Comment: @Mateo lo he intentado y me da el mismo error

Comment: Y pq dices que el error esta en el calculo de los dias, si el mensaje q recibes puede ser cualquier cosa?

Comment: El error te da en tiempo de ejecucion o en tiempo de compilacion

Comment: @Japv en tiempo de ejecucion ya he añadido el error que me da

Comment: Tu consulta es muy compleja trata de ir analizándola poco a poco, quita algun join y prueba, mira a ver en q paso falla

Comment: @Japv falla en esta linea Dias = ((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - p.Fecha_termino)).Days    , necesito la diferencia de dias entre esas dos fechas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132960/discussion-between-japv-and-huntzberger).

Comment: En vez de Distinct() pon ToList().Distinct()

Comment: Tu error no tiene nada que ver con la resta de fechas, lo que sucede es que esa consulta Linq tal como esta no puede ser convertida a una consulta SQL y debes forzar tu mismo la evaluacion de la consulta, la cosa esta en que en algun lugar de tu consulta debes poner ToList(), ese lugar es el que hay que averiguar cual es ya que tu consulta es enorme

Comment: @Japv la consulta como tal no tiene problema, fue hasta que agregué la ultima linea para la resta de fechas que me da ese error

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/294394/822