# Cómo aplicar una validación de una consulta de MySql "value % 1 = 0" en Linq c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Cómo puedo levar la siguiente consulta a Linq en c#:

```
select value from test.secuence where round(convert(value, double), 1) % 1 = 0;
```

Cabe recalcar que el campo `value`, es de tipo `varchar` en el cual se guardan valores numéricos, con decimales o sin decimales.

Solo necesito llevar la sentencia del `where` a `Linq`.

Actualmente estoy intentando ponerlo de la misma manera para mi caso en especifico pero no logro hacerlo bien:

```
return dbSet.Where(x => x.id_well == prmIntIdWell && x.DMEA % 1 = 0).Select($"new ({string.Join(",", prmArrayColumnsToGet)})").ToDynamicList();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo esto lo hago con el fin de obtener datos en donde solo me presente los registros que dicho campo en la validación sean valores enteros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no valores con decimales como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por practicidad, quizás debas ejecutar en Raw SQL esa consulta, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql Revisa este link.

Comment: @fredyfx lo intente pero las consultas hechas por Raw SQL solo permiten obtener todo el modelo de datos, en mi caso uso Select($"new ({string.Join(",", prmArrayColumnsToGet)})") para especificar las columnas como tal y así obtener un objeto dinámico.

Comment: ¿Y si esa matemática la realizas en la capa de aplicación? Por otro lado, aquí hay algo relativamente relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/294394/822 Saludos.

Comment: Tengo una tabla con valores de 0 hasta 20000, pero cada registro separado por un decimal, lo  solo necesito obtener los datos cuyo campo sea de valor entero y no los que tengan un decimal. 

Tratar fuera la matemática implica que consulte toda la información.

Comment: Te voy entendiendo mejor, ¿qué tan factible es crear un campo adicional en esa tabla, un campo computado que diga "esValorEntero" y retorne un boolean? La consulta sería filtrando todos esos registros cuyo campo computado tenga un valor entero.

Comment: Mira un ejemplo: https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-computed-columns-in-sql-server/

Comment: No es tan factible crear un campo para lo que me indicas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137626/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-marcos-guerrero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He realizado algunas pruebas tratando de mandar la validación a `Linq` y lo hice de la siguiente manera:

1. Primero, tuve que especificar el tipo de dato que necesito, como el campo especifico es de tipo `varchar` y contiene valores numéricos, pues se procede a convertir en `double` con `Convert.ToDouble`.
2. Tal vez no lo veía tan claro, pero fue mas sencillo enviar esa validación a `Linq`, solo con `(Convert.ToDouble(x.DMEA) % 1) == 0`

Al final me quedo lo siguiente:

```
return dbSet.Where(x => x.id_well == prmIntIdWell).Where(x => (Convert.ToDouble(x.DMEA) % 1) == 0).
                OrderBy(x => x.id_processed_data).
                Select($"new ({string.Join(",", prmArrayColumnsToGet)})").ToDynamicList();
```